# Views don't work based on URL - Python Django

Tags: django-urls

Can someone enlighten me????
If I use this url the views doesn't work.....

`url('EmailValidation/', CheckEstEmail, name='EstEmailVal'),`

But if I used this instead or anything random names it freaking work! Why is that?

`url('ASDASDASDASDASDAS/', CheckEstEmail, name='EstEmailVal'),`

Comment: what routes are registered?

Comment: the complete url stands as: /establishment/EmailValidation/ and /establishment/ASDASDASDASDASDAS/

Comment: the thing is, this url here is actually working. 
url('EmailValidation/', CheckEstEmail, name='EstEmailVal'), but the works it do is the outdated one tho I updated the its views it still view the previous code and yah If I used random names as URL it view the updated code. why is that?

Comment: it feels like a default route is registered

Comment: yah I feel it too, coz the previous code I'm talking about is actually existing in other urls.py and I'm guessing instead of the url I set it actually run the other one. But just how does that happened? I mean how?? When I clearly set the ajax url?

Comment: so what I did now is merged the two urls, but still I'm not satisfied cause I didn't find the answer to this problem. It is so annoying arrrgg